# How can I serve an Angular app using Jetty and also use the same server along with Jersey?

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey

I'm working on an application whose front end will be developed using Angular, the back end using Java / Jersey. I am using Jetty as the http-server. My directory structure is as follows:

```
src
    main
        java
            com.scibor
                Main
                SandboxResource
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                web.xml
            index.html
            bower_components . . .
            app.js
```

Within `Main`, I have started up my Jetty Server as follows:

```
Server server = new Server(PORT);

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");

context.setContextPath("/");
context.setServer(server);

server.setHandler(context);

try {
    server.start();
    server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And my `web.xml` is configured as follows:

```
<display-name>Web App</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <!-- Adds JSON processing to map java classes to JSON text in both directions -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Tell the Jersey framework where to search for services.  Also, JAX-RS is needed for the JSON serialization -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.scibor</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>json</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

My issue is that under this configuration, only the RESTful endpoints specified in `MyResource` are being picked up. However, if I go to `localhost:8080/` it tells me the resource is not found. If I change resource base to this:

```
context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp/index.html");
```

It now serves up my angular project when I visit `localhost:8080` but it does not serve up any of my RESTful endpoints properly now. How can I configure this so that both the angular app are served when I visit `localhost:8080` but also the RESTful endpoints are reachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was actually contained in the `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` line. It seems this specifies the base URL for Jersey, but `/*` is the base URL for index, and so nothing was being served. Changing it to `/server` fixed the problem, and allowed me to not only serve the angular app, but also hit the Jersey endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

You have some options. 
One simple is to insert angular base directory with index.html into folder on your backend app. So the url of Angular app will be 'localhost:8080/app' and your endpoint would be served on 'localhost:8080'. That will solve Cross Origin Policy problem. 
Second solution is to use grunt-proxy, which will redirect your endpoint to different port. [how to use grunt proxy](http://fettblog.eu/blog/2013/09/20/using-grunt-connect-proxy/)

Comment: or to use nginx proxy... I use this with static content for angular, and glassfish for REST services